# Changing a static field using reflection inside ear

Tags: java, spring, reflection

One EAR contains 2 WARs (WAR1, WAR2) Both these WARS have a dependency jar (JAR1).

JAR1 has a class (CLASS1) and in it, is a static field `private String STATIC1 = "DEFAULT_VAL";` this works for WAR2 but **not** for WAR1. So I've added a service in WAR1 to modify it :

```
@Service
public class ModService {
    @PostConstruct
    public void modMyVal() {
        Field declaredField = CLASS1.class.getDeclaredField("STATIC1");
        declaredField.setAccessible(true);
        declaredField.set(this, "NEW_VAL_FOR_WAR1");
    }
}
```

To my surprise, everything is working fine in WAR2. I was expecting WAR2 to have NEW_VAL_FOR_WAR1. Both the WARs are loaded inside the same ear,jvm,server - they both depend on the same jar. How is that static field not changed for WAR2 ?

Few other pointers:

- Jar1 is provided by 3rd party, so don't have control over the source.
- Jar1 is residing inside WAR1/WEB-INF/lib & WAR2/WEB-INF/lib
- Server is weblogic.
- I'm happy that it worked :). But curious how is it working internally, and what's saving my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both WARs have their own classloader. Loading the class from the JAR once for each WAR gives you 2 instances of the `Class`, therefore your WARs can see "their version" of the member variables instead of shared state like you expected.

You can also imagine what kind of bugs you could cause with this kind of hackery, so I'd avoid making a habit out of this.

Comment: First line explains it all, thanks. As for the advice not to use it: advice taken, this will be temporary until 3rd party gives a hook to load it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat using different `WebAppClassLoader` to load different webapp context. In other word, classes from WAR1 is different from classes from WAR2, although they are have same package and class name.

So `CLASS1.class` in WAR1 is different with `CLASS1.class` in WAR2. Of course, set field in WAR1.CLASS1 will not affect WAR2.CLASS1.

Comment: This is really not applicable to the question. EAR archives don't get deployed to web containers. And it follows that Tomcat would have to isolate class loaders, because no 2 WARs would ever be part of the same application...

Comment: In my case it's weblogic but I guess it holds true here also. The thing which confused me was.. since I'm combining war1 & war2 into an ear and then deploying, assumed there will be only one classloader for both wars.

Comment: @AnandRockzz Right. But just watch out as you explore application servers... Class loader isolation for web modules is just the default. Some application servers allow you to reconfigure that so that the WAR will first search the parent's class loader (such that classes in ear/lib may in fact be shared by 2 web modules)

Comment: If there are only one classloader,then webbapp1 state change will affect webapp2.For example,if we are using jpa,then both webapp1 and webapp2 use same entityManager,these will be dangerious :)

Comment: That's a good point, I'll play around moving the jar into ear and see what happens.. again this is temporary, will get rid of all this once we upgrade the jar.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele  You are right, ClassLoader has inheritance hierarchy too :)